# Issue with adding count to "subsubsub" aka quick links on custom_post_type

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm missing a basic concept. I'm trying to add several "subsubsub" links or quick links to

`"All | published | draft | trash".`

Trying to add "Returned Custom Post Type (#)" and a few others. The (#) is what keeps getting changed to 0 unless you're on the page with the posts.

I just tried setting posts_per_page to the query as a comment has said here, but no change.

I have them showing up, but the count is wrong. They all show 0 unless you click on the link, then it returns the proper count. If I go to lets say "Returned Custom Post Type", the "Used Custom Post Type" goes to 0.

I've tried wp_reset_query() and wp_reset_post_data(); after each query, but no luck.

I also have a function for pre_get_posts, which just adds $query->set('post_type') to filter what's on the page, but I would assume the links are separate from pre_get_posts.

Anyone point me in the right direction to what I'm doing wrong?

Oh and the reason it's add_filter('blah',array($THIS,'etc') ) is because it's within a class so I have to specify "$this".

```
add_filter('views_edit-custom_post_type',array($this,'add_custom_post_type_to_subsubsub'));

public function add_custom_post_type_to_subsubsub($views){
    if( ( is_admin() ) && ( $_GET['post_type'] == 'custom_post_type' ) ) {

         $query = array(
             'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'meta_key'    => 'special_meta_key'
         );

         $result = new WP_Query($query);
         $class = ($_GET['special_meta_key'] == '1' && $_GET['special_meta_key_returned'] != '1') ? ' class="current"' : '';

         $views['custom_post_type'] = sprintf(__('<a href="%s" '.$class.'>custom_post_type Vouchers <span class="count">(%d)</span></a>', 'custom_post_type' ), admin_url('edit.php?post_type=custom_post_type&special_meta_key=1'), $result->found_posts);

         $querytwo = array(
             'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'meta_key'    => 'special_meta_key',
             'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'usage_count',
                        'value' => '0',
                        'compare' => '>'
                    )
                )
         );

         $resulttwo = new WP_Query($querytwo);
         $class2 = (isset($_GET['special_meta_key_returned']) && $_GET['special_meta_key_returned'] == "1") ? ' class="current"' : '';

         $views['custom_post_type_returned'] = sprintf(__('<a href="%s" '.$class2.'>Returned custom_post_type Vouchers <span class="count">(%d)</span></a>', 'custom_post_type' ), admin_url('edit.php?post_type=custom_post_type&special_meta_key_returned=1'), $resulttwo->found_posts);

        $querythree = array(
             'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'usage_count',
                        'value' => '0',
                        'compare' => '>'
                    )
                )
         );

         $resultthree = new WP_Query($querythree);
         $class3 = ($_GET['used_type'] == '1') ? ' class="current"' : '';

         $views['used_types'] = sprintf(__('<a href="%s" '.$class3.'>Used Vouchers <span class="count">(%d)</span></a>', 'custom_post_type' ), admin_url('edit.php?post_type=custom_post_type&used_type=1'), $resultthree->found_posts);

         //exit(var_dump($resulttwo));
         return $views;
     }

}
```

Comment: `pre_get_posts` will affect all queries, you need to check context to apply it to the specific query you want to target.

Comment: Thanks, that led me down the right path. Just needed a is_main_query() to the pre_get_posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pre_get_posts` filter & use `is_main_query()` function to check for the context (as you've figured out in the conversation with [@Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo)), however, don't use `is_main_query()` directly.

When you use [`is_main_query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) to check the context, it always checks against the main global `$wp_query`, instead of another custom query object you may want. So it may cause unexpected behaviour.

To make sure you are filtering the correct context, use the `$query` parameter that's passed to the callback function of `pre_get_posts` filter hook. So instead of checking `is_main_query()`, you'll be checking `$query->is_main_query()`. For example:

```
function wpse_example_filter( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // $query modification CODE
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_example_filter' );
```